# Concrete5 Enabling Bootstrap Grid in a Global Area

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, global, concrete5

I'm creating a simple website. For the footer I want to enable bootstrap3 grid.

In the full.php it looks like this:

```
<?php
$a = new Area('Footer');
$a->enableGridContainer();
$a->display($c);
?>
```

This is working fine. However, since it's a footer I want to change the area to a Global Area

```
<?php
$a = new GlobalArea('Footer');
$a->enableGridContainer();
$a->display($c);
?>
```

In edit mode, i can't see the 'Sitewide Footer' button, but I can still click on it. However the real problem here is when I click on it, only 'Edit Area Design' pops up, there is no 'Add layout'.

Is this a bug or a problem with my code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not enable bootstrap grids in the template/page type and then add the global areas that you want? Or alternatively create any global area and then add HTML which sets up the bootstrap for you? As so:

```
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
            <div id="divExampleContent">
                <h1 class="decorated"><span>Example1</span></h1>
                <?php
                   $a = new Area('Example1');
                   $a->display($c);
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="divExampleCall">
                <h3 class="decorated"><span>ExampleCall</span></h3>
                <?php
                   $a = new Area('ExampleCall');
                   $a->display($c);
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: @user1712263 Tell me how it goes!

Comment: Hi Dannn, I folowed your advice and it's working great, looks good too! However I'm running into other problems with concrete 5.7.2.1, I really regret not going for 5.6.

Comment: @user1712263 Great news! If you could accept my answer, that would be great! What problems are you occuring, maybe I could help?

Answer (score 0):

Using grid layouts in a `GlobalArea()` is definitely on the wishlist of many people, but judging by this issue on Github, it looks like it's still in development (as of Nov 2015).

[**Github Issue:**

Make layouts work in global areas; make layouts display sensibly in stacks page when you go to them without grid](https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5/issues/1227)

Until it's released, Dannn's solution might be the only real option.